# Count number of occurrences in XML child node using simple_xml

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

Hi this is a webservice that return a listo of travel packages:

```
<offerlist>
        <id_o>154672521</id_o>
        <Pax>04</Pax>
        <FlightPackage>
            <Type>Circle</Type>
            <FlightSegment>
                <Direction>Outbound</Direction>
                <AvailabilityInfo>Available</AvailabilityInfo>
                <Id>20180316|FCO|HAV|BV1554|Y|</Id>
                <ProductType>ITC</ProductType>
                <Source>PressTours</Source>
                <AirlineCode>BV</AirlineCode>
                <AirlineName>Blue Panorama</AirlineName>
                <FlightNumber>BV1554</FlightNumber>
                <DepartureAirportIataCode>FCO</DepartureAirportIataCode>
                <ArrivalAirportIataCode>HAV</ArrivalAirportIataCode>
                <StopAirportIataCode>CYO</StopAirportIataCode>
                <DepartureDateTime>2018-03-16T08:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                <ArrivalDateTime>2018-03-16T16:35:00</ArrivalDateTime>
                <ShamDateTime>false</ShamDateTime>
                <CabinClass>Y</CabinClass>
                <Warnings>
                    <Warning>
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <Type>Critical</Type>
                        <Text>E' prevista una franchigia bagaglio etnica di 1 collo dal peso massimo di 32 kg per i passeggeri con passaporto cubano che viaggiano in classe Economica e di 2 colli dal peso massimo di 32kg cadauno per i passeggeri con passaporto cubano che viaggiano Comfort Class.</Text>
                        <StartingDate>2009-11-01T00:00:00</StartingDate>
                        <EndingDate>2100-01-01T00:00:00</EndingDate>
                    </Warning>
                    <Warning>
                        <Id>118</Id>
                        <Type>Critical</Type>
                        <Text>La richiesta impegnativa di posti eccedenti la nostra disponibilità pre-acquistata (puntino giallo), comporta un maggior costo in ragione della disponibilità di classe del vettore al momento della prenotazione. Il supplemento per la classe economy è di almeno € 35 per persona a tratta.</Text>
                        <StartingDate>1950-01-01T00:00:00</StartingDate>
                        <EndingDate>2050-12-31T00:00:00</EndingDate>
                    </Warning>
                </Warnings>
            </FlightSegment>
            <FlightSegment>
                <Direction>Inbound</Direction>
                <AvailabilityInfo>Available</AvailabilityInfo>
                <Id>20180329|HAV|FCO|NO0430.|Y|</Id>
                <ProductType>ITC</ProductType>
                <Source>PressTours</Source>
                <AirlineCode>NO</AirlineCode>
                <AirlineName>Neos</AirlineName>
                <FlightNumber>NO0430.</FlightNumber>
                <DepartureAirportIataCode>HAV</DepartureAirportIataCode>
                <ArrivalAirportIataCode>FCO</ArrivalAirportIataCode>
                <StopAirportIataCode>CUN</StopAirportIataCode>
                <DepartureDateTime>2018-03-29T19:40:00</DepartureDateTime>
                <ArrivalDateTime>2018-03-30T15:00:00</ArrivalDateTime>
                <ShamDateTime>false</ShamDateTime>
                <CabinClass>Y</CabinClass>
                <Warnings>
                    <Warning>
                        <Id>118</Id>
                        <Type>Critical</Type>
                        <Text>La richiesta impegnativa di posti eccedenti la nostra disponibilità pre-acquistata (puntino giallo), comporta un maggior costo in ragione della disponibilità di classe del vettore al momento della prenotazione. Il supplemento per la classe economy è di almeno € 35 per persona a tratta.</Text>
                        <StartingDate>1950-01-01T00:00:00</StartingDate>
                        <EndingDate>2050-12-31T00:00:00</EndingDate>
                    </Warning>
                    <Warning>
                        <Id>2</Id>
                        <Type>Critical</Type>
                        <Text>E' prevista una franchigia bagaglio etnica di 40 kg. E' necessario fornire il numero di passaporto.</Text>
                        <StartingDate>2009-11-01T00:00:00</StartingDate>
                        <EndingDate>2100-01-01T00:00:00</EndingDate>
                    </Warning>
                </Warnings>
            </FlightSegment>
        </FlightPackage>
        <Dest>Cuba</Dest>
        <Loc>Varadero</Loc>
        <Struct>Memories Varadero Beach Resort 4 Stelle</Struct>
        <idd>{b6a475f2-ef5e-4d9f-8cb7-a7d8dff43114}</idd>
        <idl>{55251786-7e22-4684-89b4-7e708df5527e}</idl>
        <ids>1VRASIRENIS</ids>
        <S_type>Pack</S_type>
        <Plan>AI</Plan>
        <DptDate>2018-03-16T00:00:00</DptDate>
        <days>15</days>
        <nights>13</nights>
        <dptapt>FCO</dptapt>
        <price>1632.12</price>
        <insur>160</insur>
        <visatx>213.69</visatx>
        <promo>: 0 €  sul valore del volo e dell'hotel   -  Condizioni  da Offerta  Vacanze ai Caraibi!!!: 8,00%  per persona a notte sul valore dell'hotel -  Condizioni  da Offerta</promo>
        <scontoapplicato>3,45% pari a Euro 58,24</scontoapplicato>
        <catoff>O</catoff>
        <commoff>11</commoff>
        <Status>M</Status>
        <modDate>2018-02-27T00:21:41</modDate>
        <av_from>0001-01-01T00:00:00</av_from>
        <av_to>0001-01-01T00:00:00</av_to>
    </offerlist>
```

i'm usign Larave to parse it from webservice `$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($url)` .
I need to check if flights node have at least one filght with status Available, the i can import package, else not.
Can someone explaim me how i can count occurrences with a specific value appear in childs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) expression:

`/offerlist/FlightPackage/FlightSegment/AvailabilityInfo[text() = 'Available']`

For example:

```
$items = $xml2->xpath("/offerlist/FlightPackage/FlightSegment/AvailabilityInfo[text() = 'Available']");
echo count($items);
```

That would give you 2 for the xml in the example.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CZVS3)

If you have multiple offerlists you might do it like this.

First get all the `//offerlist` and loop them getting the count:

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/v1.xml");
$offerlists = $xml2->xpath("//offerlist");
foreach ($offerlists as $offerlist) {
    echo sprintf("Offerlist with id: %s has %s times 'Available'.<br>",
        $offerlist->id_o,
        count($offerlist->xpath("./FlightPackage/FlightSegment/AvailabilityInfo[text() = 'Available']"))
    );
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JH0Kj)

Comment: The problem is that i have multiple offerlist and i need to check if each contain at least 2 "Available" flights

Comment: @rubenSousa I have updated my answer if you have multiple offerlists.